# How to install MySQLDb adaptor in zope?

Tags: zope

I am trying to install MySQLDB adaptor in zope. I have a mac book pro with snow leopard. I have downloaded the "MySQL-python-1.2.0.
from: http://old.zope.org/Members/adustman/Products/MySQLdb/

I extracted the file in `/usr/local/zope/lib/python/products`
and then I changed directory to it:

```
cd MySQL-python-1.2.0
```

And I typed:

```
sudo /Users/dkar/Desktop/zope/bin/python setup.py build 
sudo /User/dkar/Desktop/zope/bin/python setup.py install
```

I get this error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "setup.py", line 34, in ?
  mysqlstatic = eval(os.getenv('mysqlstatic', 'False'))
  File "<string>", line 0, in ?
  NameError: name 'False' is not defined
```

I see the lines 0 and 34 in the setup.py but I don't know what should I do. Any suggestions what to do? I am new in these things and I don't have any idea how to solve this issue.
Please let me know if you don't understand some part and I will try to explain it better!

Comment: Not sure what has gone wrong, but you normally would not install the library in the Zope products directory; it is not a Zope product at all. If there is a `/User/dkar/Desktop/zope/lib/python` directory that would be the better place to put it.

Answer (score 1):

Environment that was used:

- Debian 2.6.32-5-amd64
- Plone 4.3.10
- MySQL Server 5.1.49-3
- Python-MySQL 1.2.3
- ZMySQLDA

Step by step...

1. Install Plone
2. Install MySQL, in this exemple I install using `apt-get install mysql-server`
3. Install another dependecies `apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev`
4. Edit base.cfg or buildout.cfg in eggs add:

`eggs =
        MySQL_python`

5. In buildout.cfg at the bottom add:

`[zmysqlda]
    recipe = collective.recipe.zmysqlda
    target = ${buildout:directory}/products`

6. run buildout `bin/buildout -v`
7. edit DABase.py at the line 92 and the file DA.py line 96

Where have: `from ImageFile import ImageFile`
Change to: `from App.ImageFile import ImageFile`

8. create a folder that the script request:

`mkdir -p /{buildout_folder}/buildout-cache/eggs/Zope2-2.13.12-py2.6.egg/Shared/DC/ZRDB/www`

9. Put the icon that don't exist in the folder
   `wget http://old.zope.org/Documentation/Guides/ZSQL-HTML/DBAdapterFolder_icon.gif`
10. run buildout again.
11. In zope interface management add Z MySQL database connection
12. Enter Database conection string:

I hope help yoU!

I extract this cookbook from my post here: http://julianoaraujo.objectis.net/blog/pzp/400320287, it's in Brazilian Portuguese.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what causes the strange error you get so I'm not sure if my answer will help you. I also had trouble installing mySQLdb. I found out that mysql has to be installed on your system, even if you do not intend to use it with mySQLdb (maybe you just want to use it with a remote connection).

Before building and installing, you have to edit site.cfg and set the path to your mysql_config (which on my mac is: /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config). Then make a symlink, so that your mysql client will be found:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib /usr/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
```

Hope that helps :)